# Are gravitational waves absorbed or scattered by matter?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, gravitational-waves

1. Is there an equivalent non vacuum medium of propagation for GW's?
2. Can GW's be absorved or damped? Reflected?
3. Can we perform a double slit experiment on GW's?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: no, i was just wondering mostly on the medium of propagation thing

Comment: Have you checked the Wikipedia page yet? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave

Comment: Oh. Ok it cover some of the questions, but it doesn't seem to say anything about "dampening". For example, do GW loose intensity if they travel across a region full of mass?

Comment: Oh, it says "very little absortion or scattering". But it's kind of vague.

Comment: You should edit your question to be only about those parts that aren't immediately answered by Wikipedia. Right now, it's likely to be closed for needing more focus.